# Attribute table field value question?

Tags: attribute-table

I have a field in my attribute table that is land ownership. That field is populated with all different types of ownership but there are redundencies that are just labled differently. Ex. Parks & Recreation AND Parks and Recreation. How do I combine these values within the table without creating a new layer or using dissolve?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GIS.stackexchange. Can you please edit the question to let us now the software you are using?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a good way to automate this, so hopefully you're not looking to do this for dozens of duplicate values :-)

1. Use [Select by Attribute](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000021000000) to chose the values you want to change (for example, all instances of "Parks & Recreation")
2. Use [Field Calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Making_simple_field_calculations/005s00000026000000/) to set them to a new value (e.g., "Parks and Recreation")

(I am assuming you are using ArcMap, but the answer probably applies similarly to other GIS systems.)

Comment: Probably you can start with QGIS - http://www.qgis.org/ - it's FREE. It's help me a lot with managing attributes & it's data.

Comment: @Pat This may be an aside but you can also set up a Domain for your field and then Validate the field to find values that are invalid.  My comment applies to ArcGIS for Desktop.  Please try to always mention the software and version you are using.